# $this->Auth->user() empty for certain controller

Tags: cakephp

I have $this->currentUser = $this->Auth->user(); within my app_controller and it works just fine... Except with one controller where it always returns empty, even if the user is logged in. I can't figure out why. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: $this->Session->read() reveals that [Auth][User] disappears and is replaced by [Auth][redirect] => /. I still haven't found the cause though.

Comment: Maybe add the code of that controller?

Comment: I can replace the entire controller and it still happens so it looks like the problem isn't coming from there.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have written the statement in the `AppController::beforeFilter()` method. Could it be that you overrode the beforeFilter method and missed to call `parent::beforeFilter()`? Also make sure that through all your code the AUTH-component is properly included.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem and it turned out that it was a blank sign after '?>' - php closing tag. So be patient and look for blank space before or after php tags somewhere in your code
or use this script - http://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2007/11/07/script-for-removing-blank-spaces-before-and-after-php-tags/

redirect also does not work in such case, and "header already sent" error does not always show.

Comment: Similar problem here, eventually found a <space> before <?php in a Listener attached to the Model. Needle and haystack. cheers for your tip.

Comment: thank you saved my life :) however i dont even had a ?> in the end of the file but i had a new line after last }